# Get value from nested array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is the array. This is the response of ajax.

```
Array
(
    [vehicle] => Array
        (
            [reg] => 142D9488
            [make] => Skoda
            [model] => Octavia
            [version] => COM AMB 1.6tdi 105HP 4DR
            [body] => Estate
            [doors] => 4
            [reg_date] => 2014-07-31
            [engine_cc] => 1598
            [colour] => Black
            [fuel] => Diesel
            [transmission] => M
            [no_of_owners] => 4
            [tax_class] => P
            [tax_expiry_date] => 2020-09-30
            [NCT_expiry_date] => 2020-07-30
            [co2_emissions] => 99
            [last_date_of_sale] => 2019-10-21
        )

)
```

How can I get the value of 'make' key in jQuery?

Comment: Can you put a `console.log( response )` inside ajax success and paste that result or show that full image of response here.

Comment: This is the console output. @palaѕн

Comment: ok, so what have you tried to get the  'make' key from this `response`?

Comment: I tried this code or many other:
var result = response.vehicle.map(function (el) {
       return el.make; 
    });
    console.log(result);


I got map is undifined.

Comment: `response` is an array, how you are calling `response.vehicle` then? You are not getting any error?

Comment: I am not getting any value by 'response.vehicle'.

Comment: response is an array here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211962/discussion-between-pooja-and-pala).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.